# Android changing imageview locks up app

Tags: android, imageview

I have an Android app that uses the LocationListener to determine the speed the car is going.  Currently I show the speed by updating a TextView to show when the speed changes.  I am now trying to use images of digital looking numbers to show the speed to make it look more like the dash of a car.  I show 3 different ImageViews next to each other and when the speed changes I change the image to the correct number using the setImageResource like this:

speedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.dig_1);

When I try the app it works fine for a few minutes but then eventually the phone becomes non-responsive and none of the phone buttons work and eventually Android gives me the option to force close.  I can only test it in the car so I am not able to debug.

Is there another way I should be changing the image to make it more efficient?  I have also thought about reducing how often the listener gets called but didn't know how many meters to set it to still get an accurate speed of the car.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're doing some long-running operation in main UI thread. You could give [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) a try to detect such things.